# Flex - How to find Datagrid Cell Object

Tags: apache-flex, datagridview

I have datagrid in my page and I want to change particular cell background color. I don't want to use itemrenderer. Is there any alternate ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of changing the selection color: [Flex Examples](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/02/17/setting-the-roll-over-color-and-selection-color-in-a-flex-datagrid-control/)

If you want to do more than that, I'm afraid you will have to use an itemRenderer.

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass DataGrid and override the protected drawRowBackground() method or possibly drawColumnBackground().  These are intended to draw the background for an entire row or column but you may be able to get it to draw a special color only for the cell(s) you want.